# Gatling FrontLine Reporting_ability to see response time trend

Tags: gatling

I would like to know whether Gatling FrontLine (Paid version) has an ability to plot P95 response time of various requests over different runs. Typically would like to see the release on release trending for various request's P95.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has P95 trends and you can filter by scenario/group/request.

[image]